# High pitched feedback or interference in system with amplifier and Raspberry Pi

Tags: amplifier, raspberry-pi

I have a system running on 12V currently provided by a current-limiting power supply. In parallel this source feeds an amplifier and a 12V to 5V transformer. The 5V transformer directly feeds a Raspberry Pi Zero, which is the USB host for a USB sound card. There is an audio cable running from the sound card to the input of the amplifier. The amplifier connects to passive speakers.

When I turn the whole thing on, disconnect the input from the amplifier, and attach a new input (from a separate system, for example from my phone), it sounds great. When I attach headphones to the USB audio, it sounds great. However, when I connect the USB audio to the amplifier as I've described, I get a pretty annoying high pitched sound in there. I figure this must be some grounding issue since the whole thing works fine without that last link, however I can't figure out why. My electronics knowledge is pretty beginner-level. I thought I might ensure that the ground is the same between the Raspberry Pi and the amplifier by connecting them directly, but that made no difference. Any ideas how I might be able to fix this while still using a single power source?

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer without an accurate connection diagram and maybe an amp schematic

Comment: Is this noise happening from your USB audio device or from your Pi circuit?

Comment: The noise is audible from the speakers when the USB audio device is connected to the amplifier, but only this way. There is no noise with another input or when I attach headphones to the USB audio device. I will see if I can draw a connection diagram in a little bit.

Comment: Does the USB provide precise packet deliver schedule, so the reconstruction DAC performs on an exact schedule? Or does the DAC contain a large buffer, to remove timing upsets?